# How to disable selected row in TableView

Tags: java, javafx

I created table using JavaFX. I need to disable table row after selected that row.

Here is product table:

```
private TableView<Product> productTableView
```

I could do only clear selection like below:

```
productTableView.getSelectionModel().clearSelection()
```

How can I disable that selected row?

Answer (score 0):

a. Get the [cell clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50553044/3992939)  
b. Get row by `cell.getTableRow()` 
  (alternatively to a+b get the [row](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42697843/3992939))
c. Disable the row by `tableRow.setDisable()`